# Rearrange the alternating harmonic series proof without integrals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find the sum of the following series:

$$ \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{10} + \cdots $$

(One odd positive followed by four even negatives.)

I know the sum is equal $0$, but I have to show it only using:

- the original alternating harmonic series, which equals $\ln(2)$, and
- the limit of Euler's constant $\lim_{n\to\infty} H_n - \ln(n) = \gamma$.

How can I show that with the tools I have?

Comment: Does "need to find the sum" mean this is homework? And can you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: Nice question. Shame I have to downvote for lack of effort or lack of telling us where you got stuck in your efforts.

Comment: I didn't wrote my efforts cause it doesn't lead anywhere with the tools I can use, I rewrote the sum with $\frac{1}{8k+i}$ while i is 2,4,6 but from here only integration was successful

Comment: As a hint, show that the sum of the first $5N$ terms of the series is equal to $H_{2N}-\frac{1}{2}(H_N+H_{4N})$. Then use the fact that $\log(2N)-\frac{1}{2}(\log N+\log(4N))=0$.